# Merge Two MySql DATABASES (not tables) via Perl

Tags: mysql, database, perl, merge

I have two identical (in structure) databases residing on separate backend servers.

I need to come up with some logic to 'merge' their data into a single database on a third server.

My initial design is to load their data (by table) into memory using a combination of Perl hashes and arrays and merging them there, then doing a single massive write to a local DB (also identical in structure).

I would repeat for all tables (4-5).

I've seen posts about merging tables, but not sure if I can use some of those responses as my tables reside in separate databases (let alone separate machines).

**My question is am I stuck with having to load the results into memory first or are there features of MySQL that I can use to my advantage?**

Comment: What does "merge" mean here? Do the databases overlap in some areas? What would happen if they did overlap? How many tables reference each other? Do you (or will you) have foreign keys in place?

Comment: Let me try and respond. By merge I mean I want an end product of a single database that would give me the results as if I queried the two separate databases. There are 3 tables and one references another which references the last one. Some tables have primary keys which auto-increment so they may certainly overlap with other databases in that sense and could easily not be identical (i.e. ID35 could reference two different things in two databases). As for foreign keys, they are not in place.

Comment: Add FKs. Dump the larger database, restore to the target, find the max auto increment values in the restored database, go back to the smaller database, increment all the IDs to get past those maxes, dump/load, ..., profit. But this isn't really a programming problem anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What "mu" said needs addressing, but I'm not sure I'd go with this approach at all.

1. Get the two databases onto the target server using standard mysql dump/restore
2. Use standard queries to merge them into the third DB using standard queries

You should let MySQL do the heavy lifting.

Comment: I responded to mu's questions above. I should also add though that the tables have a date field associated with them and I need to pull specific records out of them to merge. For example, I need to pull records from 1/1/11->1/7/11 from the two databases and merge them together into a single database. I don't believe you can use mysql dump to specify date ranges.

Comment: Why would you use mysqldump? Just get the databases on the same installation and query across the databases.